# Swift Wordpress Posts Fetch Page

Tags: ios, wordpress, swift

I'm a beginner for programming and swift. I'm developing an app for my small business. It's almost finished but i'm completely stucked with blog page. I just want to fetch data from my website which is wordpress, and put my posts in to my tableview. I was searching but couldn't find a proper answer. Please at least me tell me where to begin with

Thank you

Comment: Your questions is a little vague. Could you show us your code? Are you simply trying to load code in and show it in a layout? 

There are quite a few libraries for pulling in wordpress data.

Comment: the thing is i don't have any code because i can't imagine the way i should take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use awesome new API of WordPress called WP REST API, which will give you all data you need in JSON format. Have a look at this url to get started: 
http://v2.wp-api.org/

Use this official plugin in your WordPress site: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/

**Update:** You do not need to install above plugin as it has been merged into WordPress core from v4.4 to onwards.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should define models for parsing the JSON response, for example, as below.

```
import Foundation

struct Title: Decodable {

    let rendered: String

}

struct Content: Decodable {

    let rendered: String

}

struct WPFeaturedMedia: Decodable {

    let sourceURLString: String

    var url: URL? {
        .init(string: sourceURLString)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sourceURLString = "source_url"
    }

}

struct Embedded: Decodable {

    let medias: [WPFeaturedMedia]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case medias = "wp:featuredmedia"
    }

}

struct PostHeader: Decodable, Identifiable {

    let id: Int

    let date: Date
    let title: Title
    let embedded: Embedded

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "date"
        case title = "title"
        case embedded = "_embedded"
        case id = "id"
    }

}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {

    let id: Int

    let date: Date
    let title: Title
    let content: Content
    let embedded: Embedded

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "date"
        case title = "title"
        case content = "content"
        case embedded = "_embedded"
        case id = "id"
    }

}
```

You can easily fetch posts using `Combine`.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

        @Published var postHeaders: [PostHeader] = []
        @Published var error: Error?

        private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

        init() {
            let url = URL(string: "https://PUT_YOUR_HOST_HERE/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=id,date,title,_links,_embedded&_embed”)!

            cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .map { $0.data }
                .decode(type: [PostHeader].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(
                    receiveCompletion: { completion in
                        switch completion {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            self.error = error
                        case .finished:
                            break
                        }
                    },
                    receiveValue: { posts in
                        self.postHeaders = posts
                    }
                )
        }
}
```

Full sources you can find here: https://github.com/fuzzzlove/SwiftUIWordpressClient